# How can I trigger custom socket events in Sails.js v0.11?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, sails.js

Have a problem with Sails.js and sockets. For the most part they work great. I am able to subscribe to sockets on the client side (Sails Socket client and AngularJS) and receive messages from the server when updating records using Blueprint. However when I try and go for a more custom approach I cannot get the socket events to trigger. I am able to segregate clients by subscribing them as follows...

```
// Listen for game model event
io.socket.on('game', function(e) {
    console.log('Game Socket Event');
});

// Subscribe to model record
io.socket.get('/game/' + gameId);
```

Again, this works fine for the subscription, however for some more complex tasks I have to target a controller action. These generally involve numerous record look-ups, perhaps a call to a service, and finally writing a record (or more). At the end of the chain when everything is resolved I want to emit a socket message to only specific clients. I figured I might be able to use something like...

```
Game.findOne({ id: data.gameId }).exec(function(err, gameData) {
    // Subscribe to the record
    Game.subscribe(req.socket, gameData, ['create', 'update', 'destroy']);
    // Various calls and updates to game model and others
    Game.publishUpdate(gameData.id);
}
```

The game ID in the publishUpdate() call is the same as in the subscription, the endpoint of the controller action is "/game/deal", so I guess my question is do I need to subscribe a second time to this URL with a socket call? I am altering the game record so I would have thought it would trigger a socket event anyway, but it does not.

Any pointers would be most welcome. I was using v0.10.5, but upgraded to v0.11 and I have the same issue... so I guess it's me somewhere.

I should also add that right now autoWatch is set to on as is the Blueprint mirror option. However I would prefer to get rid of autoWatch and only pick and choose which events should actually emit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this issue is that you're hitting the `/game/deal` endpoint with an HTTP request, not a socket request.  If this is the case, the `Game.subscribe` call isn't going to do anything because the server has no socket to subscribe!  If you look in your terminal, you'll probably see Sails complaining:

```
`Model.subscribe()` called by a non-socket request.
```

You asked:

> do I need to subscribe a second time to this URL with a socket call

Why not just hit it via sockets the first time?

```
io.socket.get("/game/deal/123")
```

or `io.socket.post`, `io.socket.put`, etc.  All of the logic in the controller action will be executed as expected, with the added benefit of `req.socket` being a real socket that can be subscribed.

Comment: Yup, I had an http call on that one and not a socket call, my bad, adjusted it to the socket request and all is working as expected, always one that gets missed. :)